# Is there any high school level summer program that teaches Analysis?

Tags: secondary-education, reference-request, mathematical-analysis, gifted-students

All summer programs I know for high-school students focuses on number theory, combinatorics, graph theory, logic, and all kinds of topics in discrete mathematics. (I am mainly interested in UK, US, Canada. Any summer program that uses English Language.)

Can anyone recommend some more *continuous* summer programs? That is to say, are there summer schools that offers course in Analysis, Abstract algebra, Topology, and/or set theory? I am also interested in special functions, like $\Gamma$, $\Theta$ and $\zeta$ functions and elliptic integrals: just things more closely related to undergraduate level study.

Many thanks.

Comment: Originally asked at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2615974/18398), where someone suggested that the question be posted here.

Comment: "All summer programs I know" Programs for what country?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche I am mainly interested in UK, US, Canada. Any summer program that uses English.

Comment: The problem with analysis is that one needs to have a reasonable level of mathematical maturity to start it, ie knowing about sets, functions, countability, quantifiers, what it means to prove something, being able to write proofs, etc. Number theory is a good way to build up that maturity, it’s much easier to think about the more discrete things (sets of numbers) and you can build up lots of useful ideas and theorems from nothing. Analysis is harder, especially as things can be uncountable and hard to visualise. Eg one would not expect much difference between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ but it’s huge

Comment: In a first university course in Analysis one might expect to learn about: 0. Real numbers, 1. Sequences and convergence of sequences, 2. Continuous functions (and limits), 3. Differentiation, 4. Riemann integration, likely including things like Taylor’s theorem (which is not as useful as it is in applied maths), the fundamental theorem(s) of calculus, some treatment of power series, the definition of the exponential function, sin, and cos. Special functions like the ones you described are unlikely to be covered until at least a third course in Analysis (complex analysis in particular).

Comment: You’re more likely to find a $\zeta$ function in a number theory summer school than anything in Analysis before the end of a second year at university. Elliptic integrals are an old-fashioned topic. You might see them in mathematical methods courses or 100-year-old textbooks on calculus.

Comment: This is a very reasonable question. We should note that it is obvious that low-prerequisite topics will generally be more manageable, even for precocious kids. I do have to object to common presumptions that "number theory" is hardly more than _elementary_ number theory, the latter being bereft of abstract algebra, complex analysis, and representation theory. Number theory in real life bears little relation to elementary number theory. At the same time Complex Analysis _could_ be discussed much earlier... [cont'd]

Comment: ... [cont'd] if it were not for inertial prejudices that declare it to be post-real-analysis. In fact, most of the worries that typical real analysis high-light do not arise in complex analysis. Everything works amazingly well. _And_ complex analysis is a bare minimum to do anything not entirely trivial in number theory, for example. But the most-typical image people have of the curriculum doesn't allow us to get there even by the middle of a typical undergrad degree in math. This unfortunate inertia is part of the reason for lack of high school intros to such ideas. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know of such a program, but, it would be quite interesting to attempt such a program. It would stand as an isolated point from the discrete programs (ha). Probably, if you feel strongly about this, if you have a problem. Find a good professor who you get along with and propose something. Forget about a program, think outside the box. There was a highschool student who worked with the theoretical physics professor I took GR from a few years back. Of course, forging such a relationship is easier said than done...

Comment: Since when has abstract algebra been described as a "continuous" math topic??

Comment: @Namaste since about 1870. Transformation groups etc. That said, it seems the continuous side of group theory is less emphasized in most modern treatments.

Comment: It's at least, and I'd suggest more, discrete/noncontinuous than continuous, Dear @JamesS.Cook

Answer (score 1):

The answers in the comments are probably the best (in particular @James S. Cook's advice to talk to a professor at a local university if you have such a connection) but here's at least a list to get you started: Given that you've got quite a range of interested there I would suggest going through the MAA's list of Math programs:

https://www.maa.org/programs-and-communities/member-communities/students/student-resources/high-school

In particular HCSSIM offers some sessions on continuous topics, but the focus isn't "Learn Analysis." Johns Hopkins Center For Talented Youth has a topology course but that might be a little lower level then you're interested in:

https://cty.jhu.edu/summer/grades7-12/intensive/catalog/math.html#topo

Otherwise, if you're already thinking about these topics, you might want to look at a local university and see if they're offering any summer courses or math camps. Finally, if you are on your way to college at the end of the summer you should check if your school has an early entry program for declared majors.

This definitely does sound like something that should exist.